Trying to remember a movie with a girl in it who eats very thin breadsticks
The movie is live action and in English, probably released in 2005-2015.
I think the movie starts with the main male protagonist working in a restaurant as a waiter and he has a crush on a girl he works with. She's obsessed with the thin breadsticks they serve at their job. They get married and the movie skips forward in time to when they have a son. The male protagonist has an affair with their nanny and the couple gets a divorce. Then the movie skips ahead again and the son is older and begins a relationship with the his dad's new wife (the nanny). 
The whole movie is a kind of indie dark comedy and follows the male protagonist through different stages in his life.
There also may be a whole thing with a girl in a yellow dress delivering a suitcase that beams out golden light when it's opened, but I might be mixing two movies.
Any ideas?
